# Convert Image into 1D Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, multidimensional-array

I want to convert an image first into 2-D, then into 1-D array. I used reshape in order to do that. I converted image1.png which has 64x64x3 pixels into an array which has the size 1x12288. However, when I try to copy and display the first 100 values I get an empty array. Can you help me please?

[image: Test Image(image1)]

```
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np

img1 = imread('image1.png')
img1 = np.reshape(img1,(128,96))

y = list(np.reshape(img1,(1,12288)))
z = y[1:101]

print(z)
```

Comment: You have posted a JPG but your code opens a PNG? Please click `edit` under your question and post the actual image and the actual code.

Comment: The image you have posted is still a JPEG, but with a PNG extension. You have created or obtained a bad image somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create a 1D-array, but a 2D-array with one row, and you try to get second to 100th row (Python indices are 0-based).

```
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np

img1 = imread('image1.png')
y = list(img1.ravel())
z = y[:100]

print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
z = y[1:101]
```

you should try

```
z = y[0][1:101]
```

or make changes to `reshape()` call to make it really 1D array